# WSO2 API Manager Authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an application that uses Basic Authentication to authenticate and authorize service calls. I am setting up our WSO2 API Manager on a separate server but are unsure how to pass the base64 encryption from the API Manager through to my application to authorize certain service calls.

This information is not readily available in the documentation so I am not sure it is even supported.

Has anyone used this or knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide your own authentication mechanism you can do this very easily by implementing the `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.Authenticator` and set it in authentication handlers chain.

You can refer the `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator` for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the credentials when you create an API at publisher. You can check the [WSO2 documentation about adding an API](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/Adding+an+API). At publisher for "Endpoint Type" you have to select `Secured` and then need to provide `username/password`.

Comment: Thanks Ratha, but what i am trying to acheive is this; Each of our users on the platform is identified using their username and password. So when I call the API presently, I pass these along which allows me to say, get a list of the authenticated users "friends". If I am to put this information within the API it means every call to the specified endpoint will be authenticated as coming from the "user" whose details were included in the "Endpoint Type". I am looking to pass this information with every service call.

Comment: Still it is not clear to me..You have set of users, and allowing them only to access the APIs?

Comment: Yes. I have to pass the unique username and password of each user using as a Basic Authentication header to my server. Is the WSO2 API Manager capable of capturing these credentials and passing them along to my server?

Comment: I understood, here your service is not secured with basicauth, but you want to send user credentials with the request. 
As i said in my answer, we support secured endpoints. For your case it is different. What you can do is, after publishing service,
 you can find the "api" configuration in the home\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api folder. where in the insequence after the filter mediator use the property mediator to set basic auth header, for that pick details from the incoming request(which will contain your users username and password)

Comment: <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('UserName:Password'))"
scope="transport"/>

Comment: Thanks Ratha, I'll try that out and give you feedback.

Comment: Ratha - how do I pick up the 'username' and 'password' from the incoming request? I am guessing I should set them as query params? Can the property mediator pick up query params?

Comment: yes..you can use property mediator..say if you use a url like this; http:// localhost:8280/getSimpleQuote?symbol=IBM to extract the symbol's value you can define the property mediator like;<property name="symbol" expression="$url:symbol"/>

Comment: This post might be helpful http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/03/accessing-various-information-of.html

Comment: Hi Ratha, I've tried using `<property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('$url:username:$url:password'))" scope=....` however, the username and password aren't getting picked up. What am I missing? Am I placing my apostrophes or quotes in the correct place (when declaring the $url)?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication occurs in API Manager via the `APIAuthenticationHandler`, which is among the handlers defined in your API sequence definition (/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api). To disable authentication for that particular API (since API Manager handles basic authentication itself), just remove or comment out the handler. Users should then provide the basic authentication required by the back-end service rather than the API Manager token, since they will no longer need it.